# Bind request params to domain object in Filter

Tags: grails, data-binding

I want to bind request parameters to a domain object so that I can add in updating of a domain object across a few controllers and actions.

At the minute this works:

```
def addEditBeerCommand = new AddEditBeerCommand()

Map carParams = params.findAll {
     (
     AddEditBeerCommand.metaClass.hasProperty(addEditBeerCommand, it.key) 
     &&  
     !( it.key in ["tastingDate", "price"])
     )
}

addEditBeerCommand = new AddEditBeerCommand(carParams)
```

But I'll have to handle **tastingDate** (string to date conversion) and **price** (string to double), is there a way I can tap into the grails databinding?

Comment: Have you already read through the docs about how binding works and can be customized? http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding

Comment: Thanks Joshua, That's exactly what I'm looking for :) (The section titled "Using The Data Binder Directly") Looks like it was added in 2.3, the application I'm working on is using 2.1.5.  But that's given me a few ideas.

Comment: This looks very promising http://grails.org/doc/2.1.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/binding/DataBindingUtils.html

Comment: Yep that's sorted it simple as import static org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.DataBindingUtils.bindObjectToInstance followed by bindObjectToInstance(addEditBeerCommand, params)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out then.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge towards the right section of the docs. rtfm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding) is quite complete, and details all the options available for data binding within Grails. There are a lot of options available for customizing binding and this section of the documentation (along with all the rest) is worth the read. I'm sure you will find exactly what you need.

Per your comments it appears using `bindObjectToInstance` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Different solution to this problem for grails < 2.3 which isn't documented. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
import static org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.DataBindingUtils.bindObjectToInstance

...

def filters = {
    namedFilter(controller:"myController", action: "myAction") {
        // request params are available as params property of the filter class
        def cmd = new SomeCommandObject()
        bindObjectToInstance(cmd, params) 
    }
}
```